# Lost and Gained accounts by quarter (SQL query)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have this table, and I want to do a SQL query that helps me calculate by quarter, if we lost, gained or kept each account.

[image]

and I want to add a column with the account direction

[image]

with values 0: if the account was 1 year ago, 1:if the account was not one year ago, and -1: if the account was there one year one, and in the current quarter is not.

I am not really sure how to do it, can you help?

Comment: Please share the sample data (as text), attempted SQL query (as text), desired and actual outputs (as text). Also please read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WITH last_year_accounts AS (
  SELECT
    account_id,
    MIN(quarter) AS min_quarter
  FROM
    your_table
  WHERE
    year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1
  GROUP BY
    account_id
),
current_year_accounts AS (
  SELECT
    account_id,
    MAX(quarter) AS max_quarter
  FROM
    your_table
  WHERE
    year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
  GROUP BY
    account_id
)
SELECT
  t.account_id,
  t.year,
  t.quarter,
  t.value,
  CASE
    WHEN t.quarter = coalesce(l.min_quarter, t.quarter) THEN 0
    WHEN t.quarter = coalesce(c.max_quarter, t.quarter) THEN -1
    ELSE 1
  END AS direction
FROM
  your_table AS t
LEFT JOIN
  last_year_accounts l ON t.account_id = l.account_id
LEFT JOIN
  current_year_accounts c ON t.account_id = c.account_id
ORDER BY
  t.account_id, t.year, t.quarter;
```